# Selecting Distinct Fields From Joined Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I have a table `ANIMAL` and another table `CALF_PARENT`

Design of `ANIMAL` table is:

```
ID PK IDENTITY(1,1),
TagNo varchar(30)

and other columns...
```

Design of `CALF_PARENT` is:

```
ID PK IDENTITY(1,1),
Parent int (FK from Animal),
IsMother varchar(1)
```

I am writing following query to join two tables:

```
SELECT a.[TagNo]
  ,a.ID   
 ,a2.TagNo
,isnull(cp.Parent,0)   
 ,a3.TagNo 
,isnull(cp.Parent,0)    

FROM [dbo].[ANIMAL] a

  LEFT JOIN [CALF_PARENT] cp
  ON a.ID = cp.Calf

  LEFT JOIN ANIMAL a2
  ON a2.ID = cp.Parent AND cp.IsMother = 'Y' AND a2.ID IS NOT NULL

  LEFT JOIN ANIMAL a3
  ON a3.ID = cp.Parent AND cp.IsMother = 'N' AND a3.ID IS NOT NULL
```

Its returning me record like this:

```
Tag, CalfID, FatherTagNo, FatherID, MotherTagNo, MotherID

FA-56   21   AB-670         3          
FA-56   21                            CW-59         7
```

I want it to return me single row like this:

```
Tag, CalfID, FatherTagNo, FatherID, MotherTagNo, MotherID

FA-56   21   AB-670         3          CW-59         7
```

What would be the simplest way to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT a.*, cpmd.*, cpfd.*
FROM dbo.ANIMAL a    
  LEFT JOIN CALF_PARENT cpm ON a.ID = cpm.Calf AND cpm.IsMother = 'Y'
  LEFT JOIN ANIMAL cpmd     ON cpmd.ID = cpm.Parent
  LEFT JOIN CALF_PARENT cpf ON a.ID = cpf.Calf AND cpf.IsMother = 'N'
  LEFT JOIN ANIMAL cpfd     ON cpfd.ID = cpf.Parent
```

and your life would be easier if your calf_parent table would consist of 3 columns:

```
Animal_ID (PK), Father_ID, Mother_ID
```

Comment: It was the design earlier, but there are some scenarios where we have to insert null in either father or mother column

Comment: @TalhaIrfan well i don't think that null would have hurt. Anyways, if the sql solves your prob, could you mark it as answer pls or give me an idea whats wrong?

Comment: Problem is that even if I add both father and mother, it gives me only one of them. And that too father in the place of mother

Comment: sorry, i wrote `cpm.IsMother = 'N'` instead `cpf.IsMother = 'N'` (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/2802/0)

Comment: I should be sorry as I should have used some brain before copy/pasting it. Thank you so much. I loved your approach: Easy and Effective!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.[TagNo] As Tag
  ,a.ID  As CalfID  
 ,MAX(a2.TagNo) As FatherTagNo
,MAX(isnull(cp.Parent,0))   As FatherID
 ,MAX(a3.TagNo)  As MotherTagNo
,MAX(isnull(cp.Parent,0))As MotherID    

FROM [dbo].[ANIMAL] a

  LEFT JOIN [CALF_PARENT] cp
  ON a.ID = cp.Calf

  LEFT JOIN ANIMAL a2
  ON a2.ID = cp.Parent AND cp.IsMother = 'Y' AND a2.ID IS NOT NULL

  LEFT JOIN ANIMAL a3
  ON a3.ID = cp.Parent AND cp.IsMother = 'N' AND a3.ID IS NOT NULL

  GROUP BY a.[TagNo] ,a.ID
```

and with example

```
declare @t table (id varchar(10),cal int,father varchar(10),fatherid int,mother varchar(20),motherid int)

insert into @t(id,cal,father,fatherid,mother,motherid) values ('FA-56',21,'AB-670',3,NULL,NULL)
insert into @t(id,cal ,father,fatherid,mother,motherid) values ('FA-56',21,null,null, 'CW-59',21)

select distinct id As i,cal,MAX(father),MAX(fatherid),MAX(mother),MAX(motherid) from @t
group by  id,cal
```

Comment: And what would be the query if I have to select other attributes/columns of the ANIMAL table.

Comment: There are other columns in ANIMAL table as well like date of birth etc. Sorry I didn't mention them above for sake of briefing.